# How to prevent user from entering data into a form without changing the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know how to prevent the user from entering data into a form without changing the code or adding `Disabled` attribute.

For example, blocking the field to clear a given picture.

I can't apply such a scheme because the data did not persist.

```
$('.marker input').attr({
    disabled: 'disabled'
});
```

Comment: I wonder if this is possible. The form is edited in different roles and do not want to give a role of some fields already filled.

Comment: @pixelbobby Not everybody is a native English speaker.

Comment: "How can change my script to do X, without changing the script?"

Comment: Not everyone will help re-word the question after giving the OP a bit of a hard time.  Oh wait, I just did :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment (different roles) I would strongly recommend a server-side solution. Any javascript solution can easily be circumvented by simply disabling javascript.

Comment: @Siteogra What's wrong with the jquery solution you put in your question? If you have the role available in javascript, you can add a condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) attribute:

```
$('.marker input').attr({
    readonly: 'readonly'
});
```